# Is it possible to use lambdas to bind buttons inside repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I'm using a repeater whose item has a button in it. For each button, want it to run the `SaveToDatabase()` function of the item in that repeater. Is it possible to bind a lambda to the `Command` event of that button?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
var subRole = item.DataItem as SubRole;
btn_EditRole.Command += (btnSender, args) => subRole.SaveToDatabase();
```

Trying it out, it throws an exception, but IDK if that's because I'm doing something stupid syntatically or because binding lambdas like this isn't possible.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: 
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Might help if you told us the error?

Comment: Added, sorry.  I thought I cp'd it in, but apparently I forgot.

Comment: Your cast is incorrect. The `as` operator returns `null` if the cast fails. That means you're essentially calling `null.SaveToDatabase()`.. which is obviously wrong. You should look at how you're actually filling the template and if each item is actually what you are casting to (`SubRole`).

Comment: I don't think that's it. When Visual Studio breaks at the exception, it correctly shows subRole as the appropriate SubRole.

Comment: You need to provide more code then as I think @SimonWhitehead made a very good suggestion. If that's wrong then you must provide more code.

Comment: I ended up skipping the lambdas and delegates route and using the command event, but I wish I could have figured this out. If anyone has any insight, please post it.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.